# I keep getting an error that I don't understand. Must declare the scalar variable "@publish_dategenre"

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, aspxgridview

This is my code of update button in web app and whenever I'm trying to click on update button and that time alert message pops up and repeating the same error message i.e. must declare scalar variable `@publish_dategenre`.

```
void getGamebyID()
{
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM game_inventory WHERE game_id = '" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "';", con);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 1)
            {
                TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows[0]["game_name"].ToString();
                DropDownList2.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["community_name"].ToString().Trim();
                TextBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0]["publish_date"].ToString().Substring(0, 10);
                TextBox10.Text = dt.Rows[0]["game_cost"].ToString();
                TextBox6.Text = dt.Rows[0]["game_des"].ToString();

                ListBox1.ClearSelection();
                string[] genre = dt.Rows[0]["genre"].ToString().Trim().Split(',');

                for (int i = 0; i < genre.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ListBox1.Items.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (ListBox1.Items[j].ToString() == genre[i])
                        {
                            ListBox1.Items[j].Selected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                global_filepath = dt.Rows[0]["game_img"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid Game ID');</script>");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: This code you're showing **cannot possibly** be causing that error - your code is **NOT** using SQL parameters anywhere....

Answer (score 0):

fire up SQL studio, and paste in that query.

Also, try opening that table - in design mode in sql studio, see if the table exists.

It is possible that the query is actually a kluge such as

```
SELECT * FROM MySclarFunction(10)
```

Sometimes people use that syntax and the FROM is not actually a table, but is a scalar function, and that function would thus in fact need value, and that could explain the error.

As others have suggested - do adopt using parameters and not string concentration.